# How is malloc() allocating memory in a perforated heap?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I was dealing with the allocation by malloc () and calloc () on a microcontroller. I'm able to directly read out the SRAM in which my HEAP / STACK is located and one thing struck me that I cannot explain to myself directly.

Basically in my project, memory is allocated several times. So I "divide" my memory into individual allocated memory regions through malloc() starting with address 0x24000000 to something like 0x2407D000. I can see this in the memory and using the pointers on allocated memory regions.

Simply, the regions looking like:

```
/******************************************/
//                Region 1                //
//        0x24000000 to 0x24000540        //
//                                        //
/******************************************/
//                Region 2                //
//        0x24000548 to 0x24001598        //
//                                        //
/******************************************/
//                Region 3                //
//        0x240015A0 to 0x24076A10        //
//                                        //
/******************************************/
```

The sequence is as follows: The first allocation is the reason for region 1, the second for region 2 and the third for region 3 (relatively large memories). Afterwards Region 2 is emptied by free ().

Now two small memories are allocated, which easily fit in the former region 2. I expect that the first small allocated memory to get an address of 0x24000550 and the second one somewhere afterwards. However, it seems that the memory is allocated in reverse order, since the first small allocated memory gets an address of 0x24001590 and the second small allocated memory an address of 0x24001570. So my question would be "How does malloc () handle this allocation? I thought memory is allocated from the lowest address to the highest in the heap?"

I hope you could follow my English, I still find it a little difficult.
In any case, thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: "I thought memory is allocated from the lowest address to the highest in the heap?" Why would you think that?  `malloc` can be implemented in any way that the implementers choose.  There are no guarantees about the pointer you get back, except that it points to an appropriate amount of usable memory.

Comment: `malloc` is an implementation detail; there is no specific reason for it to work from highest to lowest, lowest to highest, semi-randomly, or weirder (but logical) strategies for segmenting by allocation size. As long as it returns a valid pointer to usable memory at least the requested size, it has done its job.

Comment: Do not use malloc, learn about memory pools.

Comment: BTW, your English is fine. :)

Comment: `How does malloc () handle this allocation` Which malloc implementation are you using? What compiler and options are you using on which system targeting which exact microcontroller?

Comment: Jonas, Detail: Perhaps `0x24000000 to 0x24000540` should be `0x24000000 to 0x24000547`?

Comment: @NateEldredge I assign a _user_heap_stack section to my microcontroller. An area for HEAP and STACK is not defined, so if malloc() were to allocate memory "somewhere" I could suddenly end up in the STACK .. I understand HEAP goes the lowest address to the highest and STACK the other way around. [Reference](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs225/sp2021/resources/stack-heap/)

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm programming in C with C99. The malloc() I am using is part of the stdlib.h. I also looked up the ISO / IEC 9899: 1999 where sadly the actually behavior of the memory allocation of malloc() is described as undefined ( =( ). STM32H743ZI, SW4STM32 and gcc

Comment: `malloc() I am using is part of the stdlib.h` The _declaration_ is. The _definition_ is not. It's in the source of the implementation of C standard library that you are using. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations - which one? If you are asking if there is some general rule, there is not, every implementation is different, and `C with C99` - all of them try to follow the specification.

Comment: `STM32H743ZI, SW4STM32 and gcc` So you are using `arm-none-eabi-gcc`? Are you passing `nano` (`-lnano` or `--specs=nano.specs`) to the compiler options? IF you are using newlib (most probably you are), It's either [stdlib/nano-mallocr.c](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/nano-mallocr.c) or [stdlib/malloc.c](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/mallocr.c).

Comment: The diagram in the link you referenced merely an example, not necessarily universally true - it suffices as an exemplar.  While in most hardware architectures the Stack Pointer (SP) register "increments" from high-to-low, there is no concept of "heap growth", so the meaning of the arrow in that diagram is unclear.  I would not take it too literally.  In a system with an MMU, the stack and the heap are likely to be in entirely different virtual memory segments and protected form one another.  The diagram is an exemplar of typical "simple" systems only.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `newlib` standard C library implementation in it's nano verison.

> How does malloc () handle this allocation?

Region2 is [added](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/nano-mallocr.c#L305) to the [free_list](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/nano-mallocr.c#L158). Then when in `malloc()` the `free_list` is iterated, and [we find a region greater then `alloc_size`](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/nano-mallocr.c#L220), where `alloc_size` is the requested size with added space for metadata and padding for alignment.

```
r = free_list;
while(r) {
    int rem = r->size - alloc_size;
    if (rem >= 0) // we have enough size
    {
        if (rem >= MALLOC_MINCHUNK)
        {
            /* Find a chunk that much larger than required size, break
            * it into two chunks and return the second one */
            r->size = rem;
            r = (chunk *)((char *)r + rem);
            r->size = alloc_size;
        }
   .....
```

`r` points to the current element in the `free_list`. The `if (rem >= MALLOC_MINCHUNK)` is true, then we *decrease* the size of *the current element in the free list* by `alloc_size` at `r->size = rem;` (because `rem = r->size - alloc_size;` - `rem` is the remaining memory if we had made the allocation). *Then* `r = (chunk *)((char *)r + rem);` becomes the allocated memory chunk in the list that has `r->size = alloc_size;` the allocated size.  Note that the returned chunk is offset by `rem` - so it's on the end. So indeed the regions in the `free_list` are split "from the back".

> I thought memory is allocated from the lowest address to the highest in the heap?

There is no rule and nothing can be assumed. Every implementation is different.